# OSGi services architecture: creation of service at request of consumer

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, osgi

I am developing an application in Eclipse RCP. I need help with a design decision concerning the design of a service.

I have some bundles which are used to provide an `REngine` object to other modules. The `REngine` is an interface to a calculation engine, which can be implemented in multiple ways. The bundles provide instances of REngine by connecting to a remote server or starting a local calculation thread. Some bundles require configuration by the GUI (but also need to be available on a headless platform). A client Bundle may request multiple `REngine` objects for parallel calculations.

I currently register these modules to provide an `REngine` service. The service is created by a ServiceFactory, which either launches a local calculation instance or a remote (server) instance. The client is responsible for trying out all Service registrations of the `REngine` class and selecting the right one.

The code to do this can be summarised as follows:

```
class API.REngine { ... }

class REngineProvider.Activator {
    public void start(BundleContext ctx) {
      ctx.registerService(REngine.class.getName(), new REngineFactory(), null);
    }
}
class REngineProvider.REngineFactory implements ServiceFactory {
    public Object getService(Bundle bundle, ServiceReference reference) {
      return new MyREngineImplementation();
    }
    public void ungetService(REngine service) {
       service.releaseAssociatedResources();
    }
}

class RConsumer.Class {
    REngine getREngine() {
        ServiceReference[] references = bundleContext.getAllServiceReferences(REngine.class.getName(), null);
        for(ServiceReference ref: references) {
            try {
            return bundleContext.getService(ref);
            } catch (Exception e) {} // too bad, try the next one
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to keep this model. It is nice that the OSGi service spec matches my business requirement that REngine objects are living objects which should be released when they are not needed anymore.

However, a registered service can only provide one service instance per bundle. The second time the service is requested, a cached instance is returned (instead of creating a new one). This does not match my requirement; a bundle should be able to get multiple REngine objects from the same provider.

I have already looked at other OSGi framework classes, but nothing seems to help. The alternative is the whiteboard model, but it seems strange to register an REngineRequestService that is used by the REngineProvider bundle to give out a live REngine.

How do I implement this in OSGi? As a reminder, here is my list of requirements:

1. Easy enabling and disabling of `REngineProvider` bundles. Client code will just use another provider instead.
2. Configuration of REngineProvider bundles.
3. Multiple `REngine` instances per client bundle.
4. Explicit release of `REngine` instances
5. `REngine` creation can fail. The client module should be able to know the reason why.

---

Just to add the solution I have chosen as future reference. It seems the OSGi Services platform is not made for "requesting a service". It is the provider bundle that creates a service, and the client bundle that can find and use the services. It is not possible to provide an automatic "Factory" for services per user request.

The solution chosen involves the [OSGi whiteboard model](http://www.knopflerfish.org/osgi_service_tutorial.html#white). On first sight, this may seem very difficult to manage, but `Blueprint` can help a lot!

Provider blueprint.xml file:

```
<reference-list interface="org.application.REngineRequest"
          availability="optional">
  <reference-listener 
          bind-method="bind" unbind-method="unbind">
      <bean class="org.provider.REngineProvider"/>        
  </reference-listener>
```

The class `REngineRequest` is a shared API class allowing the provider to input his REngine object, or set an Exception explaining why the creation did not work.

For the client, using an REngine is now as easy as doing:

```
REngineRequest req = new REngineRequest();
ServiceRegistration reg = bundleContext.registerService(req, REngineRequest.class.getName(), engineCreationProperties);
req.getEngine().doSomeStuff();
reg.unregister();
```

We make the assumption that the provider will never stop while the client is using the REngine. If it does, the `REngine` becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ComponentFactory](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/component/ComponentFactory.html) from the [Declarative Services](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services) is what you need. Most of the time you should rather use DS instead of manually registering and looking up the services.

The provider side should register REngine factory service (you don't have to implement the factory itself, DS will do that for you). The consmer should declare one-to-many dependency to the REngine service. At runtime, all available factories will be injected and consumer can go through them to create actual REngine instances.

Comment: Would you recommend BluePrint and the PROTOTYPE annotation instead of DS? I have a hard time seeing the difference.

Comment: I was going to suggest Blueprint and the prototype scope. Blueprint has more knobs than declarative services, which may be useful to you here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the context (properties) upon creation of my object. It is a big hastle that I cannot specify a simple factory method but must specify a class which is instantiated. Let's hope Blueprint has something like that!

Comment: Blueprint allows you to declare a factory for the bean class, using the factory-method attribute. You can use static or instance factories. You can also inject properties and pass constructor arguments, including a special property for the bundle context.

Comment: There's a good tutorial on Blueprint at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-osgiblueprint/index.html, and Tim and I have a chapter (well, two really) on it in Enterprise OSGi in Action.

Comment: It seems the OSGi Services architecture is not made for my usecase: creating services per user request. Instead of publishing a factory, I will use the whiteboard model. This is made easy @ REngine provider side by using Blueprint reference lists. Thank you all for your input!

Comment: In DS properties are handled through the "activate" method. The factory is provided by DS too, so you don't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Two years ago I tried to create Genuine Service Factories what later became Parameterized Services. However, after analysis it turned out that nothing was needed, just register the factory as the service.

However.

I do not know enough about your service but it sounds very much that you could significantly simplify things by removing control from the client bundle, the client bundle should just use whatever REngine service is available in the service registry, maybe with a property signalling its use type if there are multiple bundles that need REngines and they should not share the same REngine (which should rarely be the case).

If that model is possible, it usually significantly simplifies. I generally then use DS with Configuration Admin configurations that drive the instances (one of the most useful aspects of DS, see http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Components). With the metatype integration, you even get a user interface to edit your configuration properties.

Comment: This would probably be the simplest implementation. A bundle getting a service would trigger the registration of a new service.

Comment: Aha! So the solution would be to provide a listing of "I want you to create the following REngine instances" using the Configuration Admin, and then getting the services. I can probably communicate exceptions by publishing an exception instead of the REngine object itself. Only issue remaining are timing issues between requesting the service and getting the service.

Comment: Getting a service will not trigger a new registration. There are two steps: the client bundle takes whatever is in the registry, configuration admin defines what is available through DS components. With DS components, timing is of no concern since you express your dependencies. Never use ServiceReferences unless you are some middleware developer ... DS is incredibly clean, especially with the annotations

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to register the REngineFactory as the service rather than the REngine implementation itself and return the factory from the getService method. That way the clients can look up the factory and, on successfully finding one, use it to get a new REngine implementation.